# Zephyr Bioharness API - Getting periodic packets

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I got a BT-connection with a Zephyr Bioharness Device thats works proper well, but i got problems in receving periodic packets.
The API told me to set the flag on 1, but im just getting a response message when im setting the flag to 0. 
The API tells that the 4rd Byte is the Transmission State (Payload), 1= enabled, 0 = disabled and

"There is no data payload within the message as the packet merely acknowledges that 
the data was accepted and that the remote unit has set the transmission state to the 
requested mode. "

Example:

Request:

```
    // Set General Data Packet Transmit State
    stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x02, 0x14, 1, 1, 0x00, 0x03 }, 0, 6);
```

Response:

```
No Response
```

Request:

```
stream.Write(new byte[] { 0x02, 0x14, 1, 0, 0x00, 0x03 }, 0, 6);
```

Response:

```
Message: 0x02 0x14 0x00 0x00 0x06
```

I got the problem with any kinds of periodic packets, just getting the responde when setting their state to 0. But i am succesfully receiving Event Packets. Tried 0x01 as flag aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, i just forgot to calculate the CRC8 (Byte at position 6). When i set the connection state to 0 the CRC is 0 aswell, thats why im getting a response message then.